# Register a new XLA device in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Scanning the source, I cannot find out how to register an XLA device in Tensorflow. For normal devices, there are macros like, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/threadpool_device_factory.cc#L48)

How do I do it with XLA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think thats a record time self post.

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc#L59)